# Convenience init for UIViewController not appearing when added via extension

Tags: ios, swift

I'm wanting to add a convenience initilizer to UIViewController via an extension because I want all UIViewControllers/UIViewController subclasses to have access to it. But when I add it, it doesn't appear in the drop down list of available initilizers and if I try to use it I get an error saying `Missing argument label 'coder:' in call`.

```
extension UIViewController {
   convenience init(test: String) {
   self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
   print(test)
 }

let testController = TestController(test: "Hello World!") // Missing argument label 'coder:' in call
```

Is there some kind of trick to get this to work?

I am able to add convenience initilizer's to other UIKit classes and have them appear as available inits.

Comment: looks fine, try clean and build

Comment: Yeah, did the same on a Playground and worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**Its working fine as you can check and match your code, maybe you need to delete derived data:**

```
extension UIViewController {
    convenience init(test: String) {
        self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        print(test)
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textf: UITextField!
    var doubleValue: Double?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let testController = SecondViewController(test: "ffwfew")
        print(testController)
    }
}
```

Comment: Found the problem. I had a left over `required init` that was still in my view controller, so the compiler was forcing me to go through that.

Comment: Yes, You have to remove it